# How do I assemble multiple assembly files into multiple object files with a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I want to be able to turn all the *.asm files in a folder to *.o files. For example, if I have header.asm and main.asm, I want header.o and main.o. Nasm can only assemble 1 input file to 1 output file.
I have tried this:

```
%.o : %.asm
        nasm -f elf64 $(patsubst %.o,%.asm,$@) -o $@
```

along with multiple other things but to no success.

Comment: Should be quite enough for any and all .asm files. Now what target do you specify, and which .o files does it depend on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere you have to tell make what files you want to assemble.  A pattern rule is just a *template* for how to build a `.o` from a `.asm`.  It's not an instruction that says "go find all `.asm` files and turn them into `.o` files".  It's a template that says, *IF* you want to build a `.o` file, and you can find a `.asm` file, then here's how you can turn the latter into the former.

So, you need a pattern rule to describe how to build things:

```
%.o : %.asm
        nasm -f elf64 $< -o $@
```

then you *also* need a list of the things you want to build; say:

```
all: foo.o bar.o baz.o
```

(since you haven't told us anything about the names of the `.asm` files you want to build I just used random names).